# How to fix getApplication() from this?

Tags: android

I have two classes, this one is XMLParser.java extends the activity and execute the ClassAsynTask. Now Im having problem in my ClassAsyncTask, in onPostExecute part where you can find the getApplicationContext(), How can I fix this error? thanks

```
public class XMLParser extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ClassAsyncTask aObj = new ClassAsyncTask(
            "http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml");
    aObj.execute();

    /* layout to display the view */
    aObj.linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    aObj.linearLayout.setOrientation(1);

    /* Set the ContentView to layout for display */
    this.setContentView(aObj.linearLayout);

}

}
```

This is the ClassAsyncTask.java

```
public class ClassAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


String targetURL;
TextView name[], website[], category[];
LinearLayout linearLayout;

public ClassAsyncTask(String site){
    targetURL = site;
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    try {

        /* Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /* Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(targetURL);

        /* Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
    return null;
}

/* Return-value from doInBackground */
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    /* Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
    SiteList sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

    /* Assign TextView array length by arrayList size */
    name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
    website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
    category = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

    int h = sitesList.getName().size();
    /* Set the result text in TextView and add it to layout */
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {

        //This is where Im getting the error.
        name[i]= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        name[i].setText("Name = " + sitesList.getName().get(i));

        website[i]= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        website[i].setText("Website = " + sitesList.getWebsite().get(i));

        category[i]= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        category[i].setText("Website Category = " + sitesList.getCategory().get(i));

        linearLayout.addView(name[i]);
        linearLayout.addView(website[i]);
        linearLayout.addView(category[i]);

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass the context into your `AsyncTask` constructor and then use it when required:

```
public class ClassAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
    Context context;
    ...

    public ClassAsyncTask(String site, Context ctx){
        targetURL = site;
        context = ctx;
    }

    ...

}
```

And create the task as:

```
ClassAsyncTask aObj = new ClassAsyncTask(
        "http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml", this);
```

Comment: Thanks Man. Very helpful site and the people around here.

Comment: Aleks G, I have a new problem. After putting my ClassAsyncTask in my own Library, I got an error in my XMLParser. The linearLayout have red lines on it and when I hover the message is "The field ClassAsyncTask.linearLayout is not visible". Have any Idea?

Comment: @aaaaAndroid This is clearly a different issue.  I suggest you post it as a separate question.

Comment: Ok. posted a new question for it. Here is the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310431/how-can-linearlayoutlinearlayout-be-visible-in-my-class

Answer (score 1):

You can create a constructor  then you can use this context.
private Context context;

```
ClassAsyncTask(Context context){
 this.context=context;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate method put this:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

Use context variable in place of `getApplicationContext()` in `onPostExecute`